# List to tibble: set names properly

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

If I have a list in R, say `my_list <-  list(id = 1, name = list(first = "Jack", last = "Smith"), qualified = T)`, how can I transform it into a tibble with 1 row and 4 columns: id, name_first, name_last and qualified? I would like a solution that doesn't depend on column names - I could do it with `rename` or `select` but the list names can vary and I'd like a more flexible solution.

One possible way to achieve the content is `my_list %>% purrr::map_depth(1, as_tibble) %>% as_tibble() %>% unnest(name)` but the names are not what I need and it still depends one knowing the column "name".

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

JDie's answer below works pretty nicely for my example, but for the following one, it does not. I'd like each list to be one line in the new tibble: `my_list <- list(list(id = 1, name = list(first = "Jack", last = "Smith"), qualified = T), list(id = 2, name = list(first = "John", last = "Adams"), qualified = T))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible `tidyverse` approach which admittedly is more complicated than the approach by @JDie:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_list <- list(id = 1, name = list(first = "Jack", last = "Smith"), qualified = T)

my_list |>
  # Wrap the list in a list to avoid
  # that the elements are spread over multiple
  # rows when converting to a tibble
  map_if(is.list, list) |>
  as_tibble() |>
  unnest_wider(where(is.list))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>      id first last  qualified
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <lgl>    
#> 1     1 Jack  Smith TRUE

my_list <- list(
  list(id = 1, name = list(first = "Jack", last = "Smith"), qualified = T),
  list(id = 2, name = list(first = "John", last = "Adams"), qualified = T)
)

my_list %>%
  map(
    ~ map_if(.x, is.list, list) |>
      as_tibble() |>
      unnest_wider(where(is.list))
  ) |>
  list_rbind()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>      id first last  qualified
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <lgl>    
#> 1     1 Jack  Smith TRUE     
#> 2     2 John  Adams TRUE
```

Comment: `unnest_wider(unnest_wider(tibble(my_list), my_list), name)`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need. It seems pretty straightforward.

```
data.frame(my_list)
data.frame(my_list) %>% as_tibble()

names(data.frame(my_list))
dim(data.frame(my_list))
```

Comment: Thanks JDie, your answer works greatly for my first example - and couldn't be more simple! I've added an edit to be closer to what I need.

Comment: Similar to my tidyverse approach you could do `lapply(my_list, data.frame) |> 
  do.call("rbind.data.frame", args = _) |> as_tibble()` to generalize to the multi row case.

Answer (score 0):

For your more complex case we can use a combination of `tibble::enframe()`  and `tidyr::unnest_wider()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_list <- list(list(id = 1, name = list(first = "Jack", last = "Smith"), qualified = T),
                list(id = 2, name = list(first = "John", last = "Adams"), qualified = T))

enframe(my_list) |> 
  select(!name) |> # we don't need the `name` column, since we already have an `id`
  unnest_wider(value) |> 
  unnest_wider(name)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>      id first last  qualified
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <lgl>    
#> 1     1 Jack  Smith TRUE     
#> 2     2 John  Adams TRUE
```

*Update*

I just saw Onyambu's comment above, and this makes it even one line shorter:

```r
tibble(my_list) |> 
  unnest_wider(my_list) |> 
  unnest_wider(name)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>      id first last  qualified
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <lgl>    
#> 1     1 Jack  Smith TRUE     
#> 2     2 John  Adams TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>